# button doesn't dissapear onClick (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code for making the button not visible and it works for a second and then button comes again. The links on navigates on the same page
I have tried "return false;" but then my navigation doesn't work.

What to do for keeping the button hidden?

**JavaScript**

```
function btn_hide(){

    document.getElementById("btn_shfaqe").style.display="none";
}
```

**html**

```
<a href="?tip=fin&vid_id=0" onClick="btn_hide();">test1</a>
```

Comment: Are you sure `document.getElementById("btn_shfaqe")` actually gets an element? Check the output of this `console.log(document.getElementById("btn_shfaqe").length);`

Comment: It's an anchor tag... It redirects on another page

Comment: Please provide your requirement.

Comment: the redirection is in the same page... I want when the link is clicked button to go away

Comment: @Barlet, This is not possible because you have added '?' in your URL. So, it will reload your page. I will try to achieve same thing another way and get back to you.

Comment: Can you include the HTML element you want to hide? Or do you want to hide the anchor itself?

Comment: let me tell like this my problem: if my address http://localhost:8080/taxreport1.asp?tip=fin&vid_id=0 contain tip=fin&vid_id=0 or tip=fin&vid_id=5 hide button

Comment: @Barlet why don't you try my answer?

Comment: @Barlet - How about my updated answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do two things; Return the function and return false, like this:

**javascript**

```
function btn_hide(){

    document.getElementById("btn_shfaqe").style.display="none";
    return false;
}
```

**html**

```
<a href="?tip=fin&vid_id=0" onClick="return btn_hide();">test1</a>
```

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ucK92/8/)

**EDIT *according to comment***
You are better off hiding the button serverside, but if you really want to use javascript you can do this on page load:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

window.onload = function() {
    var vid_id = getParameterByName('vid_id');
    if (vid_id == 0 || vid_id == 5) {
        document.getElementById("btn_shfaqe").style.display="none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost correct. You only need to make sure that document.getElementById("btn_shfaqe") actually points to the right anchor (it's missing an id attribute) ;-)

Comment: @Prutswonder - You're probably mixing up jQuery with javascript.

Comment: Nope, your code is correct, but the HTML anchor needs an id attribute. Or you can use this.style.display (...)

Comment: @Prutswonder - I don't think it's the `a` element he wants to hide. He didn't have an id on it in his question either.

Answer (score 1):

It is an anchor tag . I will navigate you to another page .

If you don't want to navigate to another page you may use

**javascript:void(0)**

as

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="btn_hide();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this fot javascript :

```
<script>
    function visibilite() {
        var targetElement = document.getElementById(\'div_connexion\');
        targetElement.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

and this in the html :

```
<div id="div_connexion"><a class="connexion" href="javascript:visibilite();">Connexion</a></div>
```

I have this on my website and when I click on the div it desapear until the user refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with thw below code snippet.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getParameterByName(name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
            var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
            return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }

        function btn_hide() {
            document.getElementById("btn_shfaqe").style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
        <div>
        <button id="btn_shfaqe" style="display: none">
            jayesh</button>
        <a href="?tip=fin&vid_id=0" onclick="btn_hide();">test1</a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (getParameterByName("tip") == "") {
                document.getElementById("btn_shfaqe").style.display = "";
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He does not want to hide Anchor tag... He wants to hide some button with id.

Comment: I have updated my above code snippet as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

> The links on navigates on the same page I have tried "return false;" but then my navigation doesn't work.

You want to hide the link **and** still be able to navigate?

There are two ways of solving the problem:

1. Server-side: add a parameter to your url, like so: `?tip=fin&vid_id=0&hideButton=1` and on server side apply the `display: none;` style to your element if it is set. If you're using PHP, something along the lines of the following should do the trick:

   `<?php if (isset($_GET['hideButton'])) { echo 'style="display: none;"'; }`
2. Client-side: write some flag value to `localStorage` when button is clicked. When the page is loaded, check if the flag is set. If it is set - hide the anchor.

   ```
   // Onclick handler:
   myButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
       localStorage.setItem('hideButton', 'yes');
   }, false);

   // Onload handler:
   window.addEventListener('load', function () {
       if (localStorage.getItem('hideButton') === 'yes') {
           myButton.style.display = 'none';
       }
   });
   ```

Using one of these ways will hide the link while keeping navigation working. You don't even need to hide the button in the onclick event handler.